# excel2013, how to automate assigning unique id to random repeated rows

Tags: excel

For QGIS, I have provinces (34) and districts (398), each has a unique id. Based on the incidents the provinces and districts are repeated almost 9 thousand times. I want to know how to assign the id to each row, so the locations are recognizable by QGIS. I am going to attach a sample here of the exact table. I tried the VLOOKUP functions, it returns, reference error. Not sure if I have given the right values to the function – Hitch 17 hours ago
something like this: VLOOKUP(G2:G9,E2:E9,$A2:$A9,0), it returns an error (reference error). I am trying to tell, to look for DIST names, compare to manually Identified column (E) , then return value of Column (A), else False

```
A       B       C       D                E          F       G      H
PROVID  PROV_NA DISTID  DIST_NA                     PROV    DIST
1       Kabul   101     Kabul                       Badghis Gormach
1       Kabul   102     Dih Sabz                    Kabul   Kabul
1       Kabul   103     Mir Bacha Kot               Herat   Gulran
20      Herat   2004    Pashtun Zarghun             Herat   Karukh
20      Herat   2005    Karukh                      Herat   Hirat
20      Herat   2006    Koshk                       Kabul   Kabul
20      Herat   2007    Gulran                      Helmand Sangin
23      Helmand 2312    Sangin                      Helmand Sangin
23      Helmand 2313    Reg                         Helmand Nawa-e Barakzayi
```

I would appreciate knowing a formula or way of how to assign IDs from Column A and D to F and H respectively. especially districts id, as districts are repeated over hundreds times.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest showing what you have tried to solve this issue. In order to ask for debugging help, showing your work will help you get better answers.

Comment: @tysonwright, thank you for editing and comments. I tried the VLOOKUP functions, it returns, reference error. Not sure if I have given the right values to the function

Comment: something like this: VLOOKUP(G2:G9,E2:E9,$A2:$A9,0), it returns an error (reference error).
I am trying to tell, to look for DIST names, compare to manually Identified column (E) , then return value of Column (A), else False.

Comment: Cool, yes that's what i'm talking about -- edit your question to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In column G use `=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(F2,$B$2:$B$10,0)),"")`

In column J use `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$10,MATCH(H2,$D$2:$D$10,0)),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great. 

Is there any formula that I can use to find and replace the correct spelling from index columns in the data file. Such as I want to find all text (Hilmand) in the data file and replace with (Helmand). 
An easy way to automat Find and Replace function.

Comment: Can you mark this answer as the answer for your question. I'm working on my reputation :) Oh this should be another question in stack... anyway for that you can use `SUBSTITUTE` as the first parameter in `MATCH` it will be something like: `MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(F8,"Hilmand","Helmand"),$B$2:$B$10,0)`. But if you have more wrong words use `Ctrl + H` to replace massively or if you want to go even farther you will need VBA or Power Query for automatize the process.

Comment: I have a very large number of wrong spelt contents. It took me the whole day to manually find and replace a couple thousands of the names.I need a formula or macro to look at the ProvID OR Name, then assign the right spelt DIST Name from the INDEX table to the data table.